# Filter on directory and all subdirectories in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to set up a filter to include only data for a particular directory and all its sub directories.

For example, I would like to include data from `dogs` directory and subdirectories

```
http://www.mysite.com/dogs/
http://www.mysite.com/dogs/index.htm
http://www.mysite.com/dogs/breeds.htm
http://www.mysite.com/dogs/puppies/
http://www.mysite.com/dogs/puppies/index.htm
http://www.mysite.com/dogs/puppies/care/
http://www.mysite.com/dogs/puppies/care/feeding.htm
```

When creating a new filter I think I should select a `Pre-defined filter` to `Include only` `traffic to the subdirectories` `that begin with` the subdirectory `/dogs/` and `not case sensitive`.

I am just a bit confused about whether it should be `that begin with` or `that are equal to`. Am I right to use `that begin with` in my situation and is my subdirectory value correct?

(I ask because it takes 24 hours for the data to update so getting it wrong costs a lot of time)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I was right. To filter on a directory and all subdirectories the settings should be

- Predefined-Filter
- Include Only
- traffic to the subdirectories
- that begin with
- /dogs/
- Not case sensitive